# Apache The Requested URL has not been found on this server

Tags: apache, vps

So, I'm trying to get Codiad on my VPS so that me and a friend can work on a project together, and when I try to index localhost/codiad it gives me this error:

```
The requested URL /codiad was not found on this server.
```

however, indexing localhost works perfectly fine, it leads me to the normal apache screen. Here are the contents of my default.conf file, if that helps at all:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.dsept.cf
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /codiad /home/Tide/Codiad
<Directory "/home/Tide/Codiad">
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
```

I'm also following this guide if that helps too: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-codiad-a-web-based-ide-on-an-ubuntu-vps, the directory of default.conf is /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf

Comment: The user that Apache run as quite often cannot look into your home directory as the permissions on your home directory prohibit other users looking in it. What are the permissions on the home directory of that account?

Comment: I honestly don't know, is there anyway to check @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Never mind, I chmod'd /home/Tide to 777 and still it doesn't work, I thought I'd add, the icon thing changes to the Codiad logo, thumbnail thing, like the picture, I can't explain it, just try indexing dsept.cf/Codiad and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Are you actually using the URL which has ``www.dsept.cf`` in it. If you aren't and there is an earlier ``VirtualHost`` in that Apache configuration, it will not use your one as that is setup to for name based virtual hosting, which requires the hostname in the URL. It will therefore fallback to the first ``VirtualHost`` in the configuration.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton yeah I am, how do I change the first virtualhost?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton well, I fixed it for the most part, now if you try to index it gives me a 500 error.

Comment: The Apache error logs should tell you something. Have you looked in them to see what it says?

Answer (score 0):

1) are you sure there should be:

```
localhost/codiad
```

or :

```
localhost/Codiad
```

2) have you ever changed  that .conf? If so, you may have to edit that .conf and add `codiad` alias/path correctly. Is everything accurate there?

Comment: yeah everything is accurate.

Comment: @MrBleach do you have any `index` file in codiad folder?